# Jest + React JS testing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am just getting acquainted with testing and I have a little problem. I'm trying to test the functions of a component that change state and call functions of a document. In the documentation of Jest and Enzyme, I did not find the right example. Here is a sample code:

```
class EditableText extends React.PureComponent {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isEditing: false,
        currentValue: null
    };
    this.textAreaRef = React.createRef();
}
onClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.isEditing) {
        this.setState({ isEditing: true });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.textAreaRef.current.focus();
        }, 100);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
        document.addEventListener('click', this.onOutsideClick);
    }
};
onOutsideClick = e => {
    if (e.target.value !== this.state.currentValue) {
        this.closeEditMode();
    }
};
closeEditMode() {
    this.setState({ isEditing: false });
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.onOutsideClick);
}
onKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.code === 'Enter') {
        this.onUpdateValue();
    } else if (e.code === 'Escape') {
        this.closeEditMode();
    }
};
onUpdateValue = () => {
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.currentValue || this.props.value);
    this.closeEditMode();
};
render() {
    const { isEditing, currentValue } = this.state;
    const { value } = this.props;
    return isEditing ? (
        <TextArea
            className="editable-text__textarea"
            ref={this.textAreaRef}
            onClick={this.onClick}
            value={currentValue === null ? value || '' : currentValue}
            onChange={(_e, { value }) => this.setState({ currentValue: value })}
        />
    ) : (
            <div className="editable-text__readonly" onClick={this.onClick}>
                <div>{this.props.children}</div>
                <div className="editable-text__icon-container">
                    <Icon name="edit" className="editable-text__icon" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How to test functions, that receive and change state and calls document.addEventListener? Please, help.

UPDATE > Tests i already wrote:

```
describe('tests of component', () => {
  test('Component renders correctly with isEditing=false', () => {
    const component = renderer
      .create(<EditableText children="I'm text in EditableText" />)
      .toJSON();
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('Component changes to isEditing=true when clicked on it', () => {
    const component = renderer
      .create(<EditableText />);

    let tree = component.toJSON();
    tree.props.onClick();
    tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

});

describe('tests of logic', () => {
  test.only('OnClick should change state and add event listeners', ()=> {
    const state = { isEditing: false, currentValue: null }
    global.document.addEventListener = jest.fn();
    EditableText.onClick(() => {
      expect(global.document.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });;
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any evidence of any tests you have tried to write. The documentation for Jest is very good so i'm not sure what difficulties you are having without more information. It's relatively straightforward in Jest to assert that the functions have been called. If you are mutating state then sometimes you may need to call `update()` on your wrapper explicitly.

Comment: I've added tests that is already written